# I can't subset rows in pandas this way: df[0] (or with any integer)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I loaded a csv and then tried to get the first row with the row index number

```py
import pandas as pd

pkm = pd.read_csv('datasets/pokemon_data.csv')
pkm[0]
```

But for some reason I get this error, as far as I know, you can subset the way I did.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/ml/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-19c40ecbd036> in <module>
----> 1 X[0]

~/Desktop/ml/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~/Desktop/ml/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

When I use `.iloc` or `.loc` I don't face any issues

I used pandas 1.1.5 and 1.2.0 and I got the same error

This is how the data looks:
[pokemon_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs1LE.png)

Comment: Isn't it looking for a column 0?

Comment: We have no idea how your csv looks like, so it is not easy to help you with this info only.

Comment: @jtlz2 this way, it is supposed to select the row

Comment: @zabop already added how the data looks, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkm[0]` calls for the column named `0` in `pkm`. That's why it's not working.
Try `pkm['HP']` or using a column name and it will be clear.

Comment: But what if I want to get the first row?

Comment: Use the loc or iloc statements which you said you were using without issue. pkm.iloc[0,:]